# Как поставить всё это в строку с помощью flexbox?

Tags: css3, flexbox

как поставить всё это в строку с помощью flexbox

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #4c4c4c;
}

.input_box img {
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="images/Staff white vector.png" alt="">
  <ul>
    <li>скидки</li>
    <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
      <li class="item4">item4</li>
      <li>item4-item4</li>
    </ul>
    <li>для него</li>
    <li>для нее</li>
    <li>оплата и доставка</li>
    <li>о нас</li>
    <li>магазины</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="input_box">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Найти...">
    <img src="images/search.png" alt="images/search.png">
  </div>
  <div class="tel_box">
    <img src="images/tell.png" alt="images/tell.png">
    <span></span>
    <img src="images/str.png" alt="images/str.png">
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="icon_box">
    <img src="images/people.png" alt="images/people.png">
    <img src="images/love.png" alt="images/love.png">
    <img src="images/box.png" alt="images/box.png">
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: `всё это`  это что?

Comment: елементы хедера

Comment: они у тебя и так все в ряд стоят

Comment: в строку                мне нужно поставить

Comment: я ещё reset подключил...

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, Вы путаете понятие строка(row) и столбец(column). По умолчанию при display:flex, все дочерние элементы располагаются горизонтально, т.е. строкой. Для 
вертикального расположения используется свойство flex-direction:column